# How to write inclusion_of validator for date field in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I would like to write inclusion validator like below:

```
validates :application_date,
  inclusion_of: { in: Date.today..20.years.from_now }

# Schema
#  application_date       :date
```

But I get

```
bad value for range
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you're getting that error is because `20.years.from_now` is returning a datetime object (ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone) and `Date.today` returns a date. Therefor your range will not work because it's using two different object types. You might be able to fix it by converting the latter to a date:

```
Date.today..20.years.from_now.to_date
```

Comment: Hmm, now I get: ``Unknown validator: 'InclusionOfValidator'``

Comment: It's just `inclusion`. See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates